# Подскажите пожалуйста, почему данный код выводит undefined и 2?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {
  a: 0,
  foo: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.a = 2;
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.a);
    }, 100);
  },
};

var i = 0;
while (i < 2) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.foo();
  }, 200 * i);
  i++;
}
```

Я хочу понять, почему код выдает именно такой результат?

Comment: что-то в сниппете не воспроизводится. Точно этот код давал поведение?

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь, во втором setTimeout задержка не 100 а 200, ну то есть вот так:


var obj = {
  a: 0,
  foo: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.a = 2;
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.a);
    }, 100);
  },
};

var i = 0;
while (i < 2) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.foo();
  }, 200 * i);
  i++;
}

Comment: ты можешь отредактировать вопрос исправив код. Плюс добавь ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: Посмотри ссылку на дубликат, тогда стане понятно, почему первый вывод - `undefined`

Comment: Прочитал, но все же я не понимаю, почему первый вывод - undefined, а не 0, значение которое задали до свойства-функции foo?

Comment: Так как контекст потерялся, и `this` в момент вызова console.log указывает не на `obj`, у которого есть свойство `a`, а на `window`, у которого этого свойства может не быть. Почему контекст потерялся - описано в вопросе дубликате.